# Run Configuration signingReport option missing Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am using Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Canary 14 Build and one of my project has missing option in `Gradle Build` tab which we used for instantly getting app signing for debug, I thought it was remove in this new IDE version but upon opening another project it was still there. Only `app` module and its list of dependency are being shown.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following solved my problem.
I am using Android Studio Arctic Fox.

1. Goto File>Settings
2. Look for Experimental
3. Under Gradle section in Experimental: Look for "Do not build Gradle task list during Gradle sync". Un-check the option.
4. "Apply" then "OK"
5. Sync the Gradle

You'll find your signingReport option available.

Answer (score 1):

please follow these steps:
1- Open 'Edit Run/Debug configuration dialogue' -> beside run app icon.
2- click edit configuration.
3- click + (add) at left then add gradle.
4- in configuration tab 1- select gradle project 2- write in tasks "signingReport"
5- apply then close.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ju4Aa.png)

Comment: This does not generate any hashes which is I needed